# ABP Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I downloaded .NET Core & ReactJS template from aspnetboilerplate.com .

I initialized the db.

In reactjs folder, I ran `npm install` and `npm start` commands.

I get this error:

> Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'.

I tried these :

- Delete node_modules folder and run `npm install` and `npm start` commands
- npm i @types/moment-timezone --save-dev
- npm i @types/moment-timezone --save

How can I start this project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@types/moment-timezone` has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/moment-timezone). Try the following:

1. `npm uninstall @types/moment-timezone`
2. Using the following code:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
```

Also, take a look at the [issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/385) on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

You have to download another package for tz.

```
npm i moment-timezone
```

and import both like this

```
import 'moment-timezone';
import moment from 'moment';
```